# How to make array key from array data value in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional associative array which has a set of array. I want to change my array index value from some array value.

I already tried some array functions but my array also contains some null array so laravel function keyBy not give me wanted result.

```
$arr1=array(0 =>array(),1=>array(0=>array('quan'=>10,'handle' => 'baroque'),1 =>array('quan'=>20,'handle' => 'baroque')),
    2 =>array (0 =>array('quan' => 5,'handle' => 'adidas')));
```

My expected result array must be like this

```
$arr2=array(0 =>array(),'baroque'=>array(0=>array('quan'=>10,'handle' => 'baroque'),1 =>array('quan'=>20,'handle' => 'baroque')),
    'adidas' =>array (0 =>array('quan' => 5,'handle' => 'adidas')));
```

Comment: you forgot the to post your code trials

Comment: use laravel collection function **groupBy** ``$collection_grouped = collect($arr1);  $collection = $collection->groupBy(function($item, $key){$item->quan})->values()->all()``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the classic `foreach`. Check if the handle on element 0 exists using `isset`, if it does, use that as the key.

```
$arr1 = //...
$result = array();
foreach($arr1 as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val) && isset($val[0]["handle"])) $result[ $val[0]["handle"] ] = $val;
    else  $result[$key] = $val;
}
```

`$result` will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [baroque] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quan] => 10
                    [handle] => baroque
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [quan] => 20
                    [handle] => baroque
                )

        )

    [adidas] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quan] => 5
                    [handle] => adidas
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use without condition by grouping at the `handle` as key directly.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
            $result[$value1['handle']][] = $value1;
        }
    } else {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/70qpD)**

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [baroque] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quan] => 10
                    [handle] => baroque
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [quan] => 20
                    [handle] => baroque
                )

        )

    [adidas] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quan] => 5
                    [handle] => adidas
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$res = [];
foreach($x as $key => $value)
{
  if(empty($value))
  {
    $res[] = $value;
  }
  else
  {
    foreach($value as $v => $k)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($k['handle'],$res))
        {
            $res[$k['handle']][] = ['quan' => $k['quan'],'handle' => $k['handle']];
        }
        else
        {
            $res[$k['handle']][0] = ['quan' => $k['quan'],'handle' => $k['handle']];
        }
    }
  }

}
```

The result is going to be like this.

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
    )

[baroque] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [quan] => 10
                [handle] => baroque
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [quan] => 20
                [handle] => baroque
            )

    )

[adidas] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [quan] => 5
                [handle] => adidas
            )

    )

)
```